# Submit and delete buttons won't work in Python and Kivy (ListItemButton)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently having a problem with list Item Button and making it work well.

Point is that it works well when I use Kivy and Python files. But when put my Kivy file inside Python using function Builder - it would run the program but if I press the "submit" or "delete" button the program quit. Here is the part of the code in Python as well as the error description. Any help would be appreciated

```
#####################################################################
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

class BOXlayOUT(BoxLayout):
    pass

class LibraryWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ItemsListButton(ListItemButton):

def submit_item(self):
    model_id = self.model_id_text_input.text + self.type_text_input.text + self.location_text_input.text + self.weight_text_input.text + self.size_text_input.text + self.price_text_input.text + self.availability_text_input.text

    # Add the student to the ListView
    self.item_list.adapter.data.extend([model_id])

    # Reset the ListView
    self.item_list._trigger_reset_populate()

def delete_item(self, *args):

    # If a list item is selected
    if self.item_list.adapter.selection:
        # Get the text from the item selected
        selection = self.item_list.adapter.selection[0].text

        # Remove the matching item
        self.item_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)

        # Reset the ListView
        self.item_list._trigger_reset_populate()

def replace_item(self, *args):

    # If a list item is selected
    if self.item_list.adapter.selection:
        # Get the text from the item selected
        selection = self.item_list.adapter.selection[0].text

        # Remove the matching item
        self.item_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)

        # Get the student name from the TextInputs
        model_id = self.model_id_text_input.text + self.type_text_input.text + self.location_text_input.text + self.weight_text_input.text + self.size_text_input.text + self.price_text_input.text + self.availability_text_input.text

        # Add the updated data to the list
        self.item_list.adapter.data.extend([model_id])

        # Reset the ListView
        self.item_list._trigger_reset_populate()

model_id_text_input = ObjectProperty()
location_text_input = ObjectProperty()
type_text_input = ObjectProperty()
weight_text_input = ObjectProperty()
size_text_input = ObjectProperty()
price_text_input = ObjectProperty()
availability_text_input = ObjectProperty()
item_list = ObjectProperty()


Builder.load_string("""


<LibraryWindow>

BOXlayOUT:
    orientation: "vertical" .......
```

Here is the error description

```
File "D:/Projects/Python/FitMe/core/main.py", line 53, in <module>
 sample_app.run()
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
 runTouchApp()
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
 EventLoop.window.mainloop()
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 663, in mainloop
 self._mainloop()
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 405, in _mainloop
 EventLoop.idle()
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
 self.dispatch_input()
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
 post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
 listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1188, in on_motion
 self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1204, in on_touch_down
 if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1189, in on_touch_down
 return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
 if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
 ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
 if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
 if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
  if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
 self.dispatch('on_press')
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8146)
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1109, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:12816)
File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
 exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
File "<string>", line 70, in <module>
File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 30, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__ (kivy\weakproxy.c:1386)
AttributeError: 'LibraryWindow' object has no attribute 'delete_item'
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`LibraryWindow` in your example doesn't have an attribute `delete_item` since you just pass.

Comment: thank you! I moved all functions with 'def submit, delete, replace and Object properties under ' the 'class LibraryWindow(Screen):'  now it tells me this error   self.dispatch('on_press')
   
   File "C:\Users\DELL\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 66, in <module>
   File "D:\Projects\Python\FitMe\windows\Library.py", line 40, in submit_item
     + self.availability_text_input.text
 **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

Comment: @Ваня Олексий I assume that this is in the submit_item method. Looking at the code you've provided you never assign availability_text_input. Also note that ObjectProperies don't automatically have a text attribute. You have to assign something to the ObjectProperty that you can use.

Comment: Okay I see you. The point is that in this situation when I run the program it goes perfectly - the problem appears only when I press one of the buttons (submit, delete, replace). The error differs depending on what I press. If I press submit it is the error I have already mentioned. If I press delete or replace - it says object has no attribute **adapter**. So it seems like the python file cannot reach the part of the code. ***** also if that could help you - when I use it as separate file it works fine - **but when I assign kivy file as window** it shows this error then. So what could it be?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using ObjectProperties and not StringProperties. However, without a clearer picture of the code I can't say for certain. As eyllanesc commented above a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example would help get you an answer.